# unattended-upgrades (xbuntu 2204, raspbian os) with telegram api notification

Tags: ubuntu, telegram-bot, raspbian

I wanted to use unattended-upgrades with telegram api notification.

The regular way is e-mail, but it's often blocked now (thank you spamers! ^^), so I tried to find a other way.

e-mail-way:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/326156/how-to-customize-unattended-upgrades-notification-emails

telegam api:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

The API was simple done, with a curl line.
But how is the safest way* with upgrades-notification?

safest way*: Work also after Upgrade or distri-System-Upgrade

My idea was just not to install a sendmail and create a own "mailer-BASH" who redirect all mails to the telegram bot. But that is not the safest way and very fiddled

Thanks for all ideas

PS: I want to use it on my private xubuntu machine, on some Raspberry PIs and on my two vservers (only last one can send really mails, its declared also as spam mostly, but mail is not really not used on them)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a clean way.
But maybe others help this simple dirty way:

```
nano /opt/sendmail.php
```

```
#!/usr/bin/php7.4
<?php

// sudo apt install php-cgi php-curl

function send2Telegram($id, $msg, $token = '', $silent = false)
{
    $data = array(
        'chat_id' => $id,
        'text' => $msg,
        'parse_mode' => 'html',
        'disable_notification' => $silent
    );
    if ($token != '') {
        $ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $token . '/sendMessage');
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
        ));
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}

unset( $_SERVER['argv'][ 0 ] );
$_SERVER['argv'][] = stream_get_contents(STDIN);

send2Telegram( 'CHATID', htmlspecialchars( implode( PHP_EOL, $_SERVER['argv'] ) ), 'YOUR:TELEGRAMAPIKEY', true );
```

```
chmod a+x /opt/sendmail.php
cd /usr/sbin/
mv sendmail sendmail-original
ln -s /opt/sendmail.php sendmail
```